# multiple twitter login MGTwitterEngine OAuth HELP

Tags: iphone, authentication, oauth, mgtwitterengine, access-token

my problem is that i dont know what information needs to be stored for each user and when i've got the information, where do i need to change that information so that my app knows it's changed user. i believe it has something to do with the access token provided, but that's all i've got.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need the username and access token.
You cannot store anything else on your application.
just send those as login parameters and you should be fine.
You will need to create an method (by keychain or NSDefaults) to store this data on your application.

I would suggest to use XAuth instead of OAuth...
Best of luck!

edit:
The username and token are set after the engine instantiation. If you have a list with usernames and tokens, on the instantiation of the engine you set them like:

```
self._engine = [[XAuthTwitterEngine alloc] initXAuthWithDelegate:self];
self._engine.consumerKey = kOAuthConsumerKey;
self._engine.consumerSecret = kOAuthConsumerSecret;
```

I use the XAuthTwitterEngine, but it is probably the same for OAuth...

Comment: Thanks, I will be changing to Xauth soon. I want to sort out multiple logins with what I have first. I have both username and accesstoken stored into nsuserdefaults, but where in the code are they used to make a request?

Comment: Hi friends. Am using MGTwitterEngine auth for Twitter. It works fine, but i showing some of new tweets from my twitter. I want to show many tweets from my twitter page in my iphone app. How to do this? Where i need to give the timeline in my application. Thanks in advance..